# Emacs: why shell-command "git log" works, but "git shortlog" doesn't?

Tags: git, shell, emacs, elisp

I can't figure this out. Why do these behave differently:

```
(shell-command "git log")
(shell-command "git shortlog")
```

First one works as expected: returns 0 and prints stuff to shell output buffer.
Second one returns 0 but prints nothing. Why is that?

Also

1. both `git log` and `git shortlog` work perfectly in `ansi-term`
2. both `git log` and `git shortlog` give a warning but still work in `shell`

Comment: I think that the answer would be somewhere along the lines that Git is trying to be its own text editor and instead of just relying on other programs to deal with the log output does random junk in the console to "enhance" user experience. Luckily, so far there is a cure: use `--no-pager` to avoid this nonsense.

Comment: tried that already - doesn't work. This is something special.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, that only works in `shell`, but not in `shell-command`. Weird.

Comment: Weirdly, this: (shell-command "git --no-pager log --pretty=short") works for me, while shortlog must be just a shorthand version of writing the same thing... But it doesn't do what it's supposed to, the summaries and commit hashes are there, regardless.

Comment: I've found the reason reading `git help shortlog`. Apparently it wants to read something from
standard input... Anyway, the workaround is `(shell-command "git shortlog HEAD")`.

Comment: Something I've found in the meantime, could be also interesting: `(shell-command "git --no-pager log --pretty=oneline --no-decorate --format=\"%s\"")`

Comment: I was mainly interested in `(shell-command "git shortlog HEAD -s")` functionality, but thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`man git-shortlog`

> If no revisions are passed on the command line and either standard
>   input is not a terminal or there is no
>          current branch, git shortlog will output a summary of the log read from standard input, without reference to
>          the current repository.

You must explicitly provide reference to work in your case,

Use, `git shortlog HEAD` instead.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you very much. Saved me a bunch of time

Comment: Happy to know that it helped you.