# Get contributors for each file using git shortlog in python subprocesses

Tags: git, python-3.x

I've got a problem, when I'm trying to obtain output of following command:
`git shortlog -s -- [file_path]`
using python 3.6 subprocess module.

Here the code:

```
import subprocess

x = subprocess.Popen(['git shortlog -s -- ' + file_path], cwd=path, 
shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print(x)
```

The result of execution is empty.
What had I done wrong?

Comment: Did you find the answer? That's my question too. everything is fine for example when executing `git status` or `git log` but when executing `git shortlog` it stops working.

Comment: No, I didn't. I just give up on `git shortlog` and obtain necessary data from parsing of `git log` output.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `git shortlog HEAD`

```
subprocess.Popen(['git shortlog HEAD -s -- ' + file_path],
                  cwd=path,  shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

To learn why, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042420/4381942